# Remove or add css style on click after a few seconds

Tags: jquery, css, delay

How can I remove or add [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) but with delay? In my example I add a border color when I click `.s_edit` and remove it when I click `.s_done`. The problem is that I don't want to remove the border color instantly, but after 2seconds. looks like `.delay()` does not work and I have no idea how to use `setTimeout` or something similar.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Bc3K/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <a href="#" class="s_edit">Edit</a>    
    <a href="#" class="s_done">Done</a>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.s_edit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var parent = $(this).parents('.main');    
    parent.css('border-color', 'red');
    $(this).hide();
    $('.s_done', parent).show();

});

$('.s_done').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var parent = $(this).parents('.main');    
    parent.delay(2000).css('border-color', '');
    $(this).hide();
    $('.s_edit', parent).show();

});
```

Comment: Try with `setTimeOut`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.s_done').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parents('.main');
    setTimeout(function() {
        parent.css('border-color', '');
    }, 2000);
    $(this).hide();
    $('.s_edit', parent).show();
});
```

Comment: That's what I tried and didn't work, probably I missed something. Now works. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JQuery, swap your function `setTimeout` with the `animate` function.
The `animate` function is more powerful and customizable .

However, you don't really need to customise your script. You can simply add some CSS effects like this:

**CSS**

```
#box{
 position : relative;
 width : 100px;
 height : 100px;
 background-color : gray;
 border : 5px solid black;    
 -webkit-transition : border 500ms ease-out; 
 -moz-transition : border 500ms ease-out;
 -o-transition : border 500ms ease-out;
}
```

Here is a working link: [Border nicely fading](http://jsfiddle.net/5Bc3K/7/)

Comment: Yes, I know, CSS3 is great but the problem is in browsers compatibility, I need this to works in all browsers, including IE.

Comment: If you want to add some nice transitions effect, you need to use the animate function:

    $(parent).animate({
        "border-top-color": "#FF0000",
        "border-left-color": "#FF0000",
        "border-right-color": "#FF0000",
        "border-bottom-color": "#FF0000"}, 'fast');
However, the border setup isn't a numeric value. To make it work, you need to add this plug-in http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Comment: I do all animations with CSS3, and I don't care if they are not working for older browsers(I just make sure that it will show the content even if no animation.), but my question was not about animations, it was by setting a delay after click action.

Comment: Calm down, I said "If you want to add some nice transition effects". If you don't care, that's fine, but I just showed you how animations effects can be added to your project. Might be helpful for some on else